# Problem trying to setup GoDaddy domain with GitHub Pages

Tags: web, github, dns, github-pages, godaddy-api

I really hope someone can help me with this since I've been struggling for days without luck.

I'm kind of new to web development and I've been doing tutorials. I already created my portfolio website and I hosted it on GitHub pages. I liked it and I decided to give it a custom domain name. I bought my domain through GoDaddy.com and I couldn't be able to correctly point it to my website hosted on GitHub Pages.

I tried different tutorials, these include [this](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-set-up-godaddy-domain-with-github-pages-a9300366c7b), [this](https://medium.com/@JinnaBalu/godaddy-domain-with-github-pages-62aed906d4ef), [this](https://medium.com/@supriyakankure/how-to-add-a-custom-domain-to-your-github-page-with-godaddy-84495781143e) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPGi1IHQxFM&t=3s). None of them works for me. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is something outdated in those tutorials but this is getting maddening.

To sum up,

- I go to DNS management of my domain at GoDaddy.com.
- Changed in the records tab all the A-type to the GitHub IP values (185.199.108.153, 185.199.109.153, 185.199.110.153, 185.199.111.153) and the CNAME type to my [username]github.io website value.
- Added CNAME file to my repository
- Added my custom domain in portfolio>settings>github pages

Not sure where is my error and if someone can help me with this I will really appreciate it. If you need more details let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the webdev world!

When did you actually register and redirect the domain? I've had multiple issues on several occasions which was resolved by just waiting.

Usually your ISP or just generally something you don't have control of does cache some stuff so you `might` need some time for it to pass in order to function properly.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the welcome :). Yeah that's what I read and I waited almost 3 days but it still stayed in a blank page. This is my domain you can go ahead and take a look: diegosimonelli.com